# Чем отличается приведение к целому после деления и целочисленное деление?

Tags: python

Решаю задачи в хендбуке Яндекса, тесты не прошла вот такая конструкция:

```
number = int(number / 10)
```

а вот такая прошла:

```
number //= 10
```

Разве между ними есть разница?

Comment: В отрицательных числах есть

Comment: @andreymal Интересно, спасибо, изучу! Но задача была ограничена натуральными числами, поэтому и удивляюсь

Comment: Ещё разница начинается примерно на числе 11258999068426249 из-за ограниченной точности float'ов (а вот у питонячьих int'ов точность неограниченная)

Comment: @andreymal Спасибо!

Comment: @andreymal Да, вот это хорошее объяснение. Чтобы сохранить максимальную точность, нужно не выходить из пространства целых чисел. Второй пример кода позволяет это делать, а первый нет.

Comment: @CrazyElf Спасибо)